# Use systemd for Custom Service

Tags: systemd, services

I have my own app and want it to work as a service. It doesn't require any root permissions. I just want to be able to start it, to terminate gracefully (e.g., `SIGINT` – a few seconds wait – `SIGKILL`), to restart if it fails once per hour, to get status – all of this `systemd` does with services. There is no need to start it when OS starts, no need to include it in all services list.

The restriction is that it must not require root privileges, and should not be installed in system somehow (or, at least, be very non-invasive into system).

I managed to make it work if it placed in `~/.config/systemd/user/loved.service`: `systemctl --user link ~/loved.service`. But it's desirable to run it directly from app folder.

I believe `systemctl` could be used for such cases like this:

```
systemctl --user start ~/loved.service
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Failed to start ....mount: Unit ....mount not found.
```

Of course, mounting is not what I wanted.

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax to start a user service with systemd is just:

```
systemctl --user start service-name
```

`systemd` will look in `~/.config/systemd/user` for matching files.

Comment: Can it take `*.service` files from custom locations?

Comment: You can use `systemctl link PATH` to link a file outside the search path into the search path. See `man systemctl` for details.